# shared preferences fails in android

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I am fetching   the username of the client via alert box in androidd

and storing it in a variable "name"
this is class   for fetching the user name i have done so far

```
private void request_user_name()  {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

            final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);

            builder.setView(input_field);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()


            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                   String name = input_field.getText().toString();



                        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

                        edit.putString("name", name);

                        edit.commit();


                    String name = pref.getString("name", "");
                    name = name.trim();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
                        request_user_name();
                    }
```

and i am calling  the request_user_name class  with

```
if(name.isEmpty()) {
    request_user_name();
}
```

so that The application will not  create pop up alert everytime i open this

but in  the emulator      it crashes    when the apk is installed

emulator:nexus 6P api 25

android studio 2.3
logcat :

> 04-21 19:46:12.921 7369-7369/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>   04-21 19:46:12.921 7369-7369/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
>   04-21 19:46:13.235 7369-7369/app.torune_sav W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.torune_sav-2/lib/x86_64
>   04-21 19:46:13.274 7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
>   04-21 19:46:13.295 7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
>   04-21 19:46:13.344 7369-7369/app.torune_sav I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
>   04-21 19:46:13.344 7369-7369/app.torune_sav I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>   04-21 19:46:13.344 7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/FA: Debug logging enabled
>   04-21 19:46:13.344 7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 75451222
>   04-21 19:46:13.378 7369-7369/app.torune_sav V/FA: Collection enabled
>   04-21 19:46:13.378 7369-7369/app.torune_sav V/FA: App package, google app id: app.torune_sav, 1:718884139232:android:90e5088fff923640
>   04-21 19:46:13.415 7369-7369/app.torune_sav V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
>   04-21 19:46:13.417 7369-7369/app.torune_sav I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
>   04-21 19:46:13.420 7369-7369/app.torune_sav I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   04-21 19:46:13.425 7369-7392/app.torune_sav V/FA: Using measurement
>   service 04-21 19:46:13.435 7369-7392/app.torune_sav V/FA: Connecting
>   to remote service 04-21 19:46:13.504 7369-7369/app.torune_sav
>   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64 04-21 19:46:13.505
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer
>   search path
>   /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64:/system/fake-libs64:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86_64:/system/lib64:/vendor/lib64
>   for namespace 0x7e277c41c0f0 04-21 19:46:13.513
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown
>   path:  04-21 19:46:13.513 7369-7369/app.torune_sav W/System:
>   ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64 04-21 19:46:13.514
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer
>   search path
>   /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64:/system/fake-libs64:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86_64:/system/lib64:/vendor/lib64
>   for namespace 0x7e277c41c160 04-21 19:46:13.523
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:5 04-21 19:46:13.523
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of
>   com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 5 04-21
>   19:46:13.526 7369-7369/app.torune_sav W/System: ClassLoader referenced
>   unknown path:
>   /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000003/n/x86_64
>   04-21 19:46:13.583 7369-7369/app.torune_sav W/art: Before Android 4.1,
>   method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 04-21 19:46:13.597
>   7369-7399/app.torune_sav D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security
>   Config specified, using platform default 04-21 19:46:13.608
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav V/FA: onActivityCreated 04-21 19:46:13.754
>   7369-7369/app.torune_sav W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown
>   path:
>   /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/n/x86_64
>   04-21 19:46:13.764 7369-7369/app.torune_sav D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM
>
> ```
>                                                           --------- >beginning of crash 04-21 19:46:13.765 7369-7369/app.torune_sav >E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                           Process: >app.torune_sav, PID: 7369
>                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ```
>
> ComponentInfo{app.torune_sav/app.real_time_chat.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
>                                                                     at app.real_time_chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125)
>                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Can anyone figure out what the issue in the code ?

Comment: Post the stacktrace please

Comment: yep sure  


 Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "app.torune_sav/app.market_collectors.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 6541 on device Pixel_API_25 [emulator-5554]
Application terminated.

Comment: edit your post and post whole stacktrace.. and edit you code couse right now it doesn't make any sence, `String name` part is after you use `name` variable, so you probably post it wrong..

Comment: no no i made name as global variable  hence i forgot to add it over this code    and the  yes i have updated with logcat

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665). Looks like you are not passing a valid String, maybe null

Comment: literally the app crashes before  getting the value from the  alert box    i have not passed any string values yet  :)

Comment: String name = pref.getString("name", "some text");

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your String variable isn't null before calling .isEmpty() en it.

```
if(name == null && name.isEmpty()) {
    request_user_name();
}
```

Or you should initialize it with a default value.

Comment: its a username   its not a good idea  to set a static default value